# having issues on connecting connecting mysql workbench to Jupyter notebook

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

My password of contains an @

%sql sql+pymysql://root:password_matt@127.0.0.1/database_name

Please how to resolve this error MetaData.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind' Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

Please what can I do to resolve this issue. Thank you

I tried replacing the @ in my password to %40 but the issue still persist.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].